# Undefined reference to a static member of the class

Tags: c++, static

I am working on a **homework** assignment, and I have almost everything done except for this obnoxious static value that our professor wishes us to use: value

The header file contains:

```
private:
    static int value;
```

And we have to have a function calculate the value, like so:

```
static void calculate()
{
    long a = 1L;
    int count = 0;

    while( a != 0 )
    {
        a = a << 1;
        count++;
    }

    value = count;
}
```

This is essentially calculating the number of bits in a long, using bit shifting.

However, I am getting the error " undefined reference to `Class1::value'

I've spent the last hour and a half figuring this out, and it's killing me. Any help would be great, all searches have come up dead.

Thanks!

---

Update:

I included

```
int Class1::value = 0;
```

However, now I am getting an error saying "error: int Class1::value is private

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your *.cpp file add

```
int ClassName::value = 0;
```

This will allocate storage for a `value`.

The piece of code that you actually have in a class declaration just *declares* this variable (makes the compiler aware that such a variable exists). However, each variable must be declared and *defined*. A definition will make sure the storage is put aside for this variable and create a symbol your compiler was unable to find before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a static data member in (.cpp) source file with following syntax:

```
datatype Your_ClassName::variable;
```