# Linking error in dereferencing static variable

Tags: c++, static, linker

(I've failed to find any similar question... so, I hope you can help me)

In a program in C++ that I'm developing, I have a class that simulates a thread. I'll call it "Test" here. In it, I have an static map (`std::map`, from STL) that in which I store some semaphores (because I need all of the threads to have access to the same semaphores). (I think it is not worth to explain why I'm using a `map`, instead of a `vector`, but I believe this shouldn't be a problem)

To "get" this static variable, I created a `getMutexHash()` function, that returns a pointer to the static `map`. But, for some reason, after compiling, I'm getting a linker error when trying to return a `this pointer`.

The following code exemplifies the problem:

```cpp
// MAIN.CPP
#include "Test.h"

int main ()
{
    Test test;
    map<int, pthread_mutex_t>* mutexHash = test.getMutexHash();


    return 0;
}

// TEST.H
#include <map>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
  public:
    map<int, pthread_mutex_t>* getMutexHash();
  private:
    static map<int, pthread_mutex_t> mutexHash;
};

// TEST.CPP
#include "Test.h"

map<int, pthread_mutex_t>* Test::getMutexHash()
{
    return &mutexHash;
}
```

When compiling, I get no error nor warnings; but when linking, I receive this error:

```
Test.o: In function `Test::getMutexHash()':
Test.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `Test::mutexHash'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to a static member of the class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380289/undefined-reference-to-a-static-member-of-the-class)

Answer (score 3):

You've *declared* that `mutexHash` exists, but haven't *defined* it. You need to add a definition to `test.cpp`:

```
map<int, pthread_mutex_t> Test::mutexHash;
```

Comment: WOW! It worked. I didn't know I have to define the static variables as if they were "forward declarations". Thanks! I was stuck in this problem for a while already =)